# How do you inherit constructors of a base class using fully qualified name?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class foo : public std::runtime_error
{};
```

To bring in the constructors of `std::runtime_error` into my class, you'd think I could do this:

```
using std::runtime_error::std::runtime_error;
```

However, this doesn't work. Normally I'd think to do this:

```
using super = std::runtime_error;
using super::super;
```

This does work, but not sure if this is a workaround or the only real solution. Upon testing with Clang, this works:

```
using runtime_error::runtime_error;
```

However I'm curious *why* this works since it isn't fully qualified. To throw a wrench in the mix, I tried breaking it by introducing multiple inheritance:

```
namespace n
{
    class runtime_error {};
}

class foo : public std::runtime_error, public n::runtime_error
{
public:
    using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

Now `using runtime_error::runtime_error` doesn't work anymore, because it's ambiguous. However, the `super` alias still works (since you explicitly pick the base class you want to inherit from), but could get nasty if you have to define aliases for each inherited type (e.g. `super1`, `super2`).

What is the proper way to inherit constructors from a base class that is in a different namespace, when fully-qualified name syntax (using `::`) is ambiguous with the `::` used to specify the member constructor?

Comment: The way to make it work with FQN would be `using std::runtime_error::runtime_error`. Please undelete the question, it contains the answer in the comments.

Comment: You keep saying "works" and "doesn't work". What do those terms mean to you? What actually happens? You never said.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe, when OP says 'works' they mean 'compiles without errors'

Comment: Within the context of the compiler, "doesn't work" means "doesn't compile". The specific diagnostics I left out for simplicity.

Comment: @void.pointer Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have a compilation error when trying to use `using std::runtime_exception::std::runtime_exception` in the class is because you need to provide name of the constructor. And the name of the constructor for `std::runtime_exception` is not `std::runtime_exception`, it is `runtime_exception` - the name of the constructor is the unqualified type. Because of that, correct notation would be

```
using std::runtime_exception::runtime_exception;
```

Your other solution with type alias work as well, and although it might seem confusing at first - why does it work with type alias, when type alias is indeed `std::runtime_exception` - it is helpful to remember that type aliasing is not textual substitution, and thus it works as expected.

Both approaches are valid and which one to choose is totally dependent on you and your code.

Comment: Embarrassingly, I admit I was completely off base in my way of thinking of this. You made me realize that the syntax for inheriting constructors isn't "class::class" but "class::member". I think what threw me off is the alias: I expect the alias to be `super::runtime_error`, not `super::super`. That doesn't make any sense to me. The alias identifies a *class*, not a *member* of the class. "thus it works as expected": Why?